Does wagtail support dynamical definition of Search and Social Previews or Slug?
Is there any system in wagtail where you can dynamically define Search and Social Previews or Slug. so for example that it goes details/1/ where one would represent certain ID. so it would be details/{id} I wonder is this possible. If this is not possible is it possible somehow to define query in route?
Thanks in advance guys.
Currently I am solving this problem with keeping in session my id and using it later in my blocks.py but I would like for the Id to be vissible in the route. Example: https://www.my-website.com/orders/2/ Where 2 would be dynamically forwarded.
